# A method using different flavors of it's own private members

Tags: c++

```
class A{

private:

  std::vector<class X> flavor1
  std::vector<class X> flavor2

public:

  void useVectorOfX(std::vector<class X> someflavor){
      ...  // same logic for both flavors
  }    
}
```

Now I want to call `useVectorOfX()` from another class, giving it either `flavor1` or `flavor2` depending on need. I can think of three ways -

Way 1: Use Getter Methods; but it seems unnatural for `class A` to get its own data through a Getter Method.

```
class B{

public:

  A *a = new A();
  a->useVectorOfX(a->getFlavor1());
}
```

Way 2: Make the two vectors `public` (*dirty*)

Way 3: Separate Methods?

```
class B{

public:

  A *a = new A();
  a->useVectorOfXForFlavor1();
  a->useVectorOfXForFlavor2();

}
```

Comment: Is `UseVectorOfX` really supposed to take as parameter a *copy* of one of the object's own data members?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about way 1 in a more descriptive format:

```
class A {    
public:
    enum {
        flavor1 = 0, // used as array index, first element must be zero
        flavor2,
    } vector_flavor;
    static const int number_of_flavors = 2;

    void useVectorOfX(vector_flavor flav){
        std::vector<class X> someflavor& = vectors[flav];
        // ...
    }
private:        
    std::vector<class X> vectors[number_of_flavors];
}

A object; // lol
object.useVectorOfX(A::flavor1);
```

Comment: The enum should be public, and the class should be called `An` ;-)

Comment: Oh dear, sorry, let me fix that enum :)

Comment: And various other minor issues: `enum vector_flavor {...}`, `vector<...> &someflavor`, `A::flavor1`.

Comment: Sorry, not awake yet (and still a "beginner" in C++, so I'll often make little stupid mistakes that would be gone in a millisec by a compiler error or intellisense.)

Comment: You could also pull a trick such as defining a final element of the enum `number_of_flavors`, and using that instead of `2` in the definition of `A::vectors`. You'd have to change the order of definition.

Comment: Yeah, I figured, but it would make no difference. If you update the `vector_flavor` enum you must edit `vectors[flavorN + 1]` too, to the final element. If you must update the definition of `vectors` anyway then I find `vectors[N] // ...` more descriptive and accurate. Now please C++, give us a compile-time `num_elements(enum_name)`. That info is perfectly available for the compiler.

Comment: That's why I wouldn't write `flavorN+1`, I'd write `number_of_flavors`. Then the array definition doesn't need to change at all when the enum does. It's a little unsatisfactory, because it means there's a named value of the enum that isn't actually a valid argument to `UseVectorOfX`, but in practice I find it easier to remember not to pass that value, than I do to find all uses of a "magic number" when I change it. To avoid damaging the enum like that, I'd at least define the size in the very next line after the enum, so that it's easier to spot what needs to change when a new value is added.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, I found the definition of the array close enough, but future code might change that. Let me update my answer. EDIT: Oh woops, I read your last comment wrong, I just realized.

Answer (score 3):

I would go for option 3. Using

```
void useVectorOfXForFlavor1(){
    useVectorOfX(flavor1);
}
```

seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Doesn't seam reasonable to me, because maintaining will be a hell and you are expressing an argument in the function name while the language is perfectly capable of passing a real argument.

Comment: @Nightcracker - Duh, the name is just an example from the question. If it was `AccumulateHours()` and `AccumulateExpenses()` would you still prefer a single `Accumulate` function and pass the vectors to it?

Comment: Depends, and in this case yes. Let me quote the question: "// same logic for both flavors". Since the logic is the same the functions must be very closely related and your code should reflect this.

Comment: some sense, at last. @night, I assume (suspect?) that "same logic" here means "similar code". This does not matter much. What really does  is **what these operations mean to the user of the class**? If they have different semantics they should be a different methods. And if you worry about the maintenance, this allows you to change the implementation without changing the API. What OP does is  exposing the internal implementation. If this is **logically** the same operation, then your solution is more appropriate. It all comes down to API design.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like:

```
std::vector<class X> flavors[2];
...
public:
  void useVectorOf(int X) { useVectorOf(flavors[X]); }
private:
  void useVectorOf(std::vector<class X> &v) { ...; }
```

Using an `enum` rather than a plain `int` would be nicer.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
class B{

public:

  A *a = new A();
  a->useVectorOfX(a->getFlavor1());
}
```

this is better because you create only one method and and you dont decrare members of the class public unnecessarily.

Comment: I agree. I don't think it's that unnatural. It's also very clear.

Comment: I still find this bad, and especially because you're __not__ "creating only one method". This is just as bad as `useVectorOfXForFlavor1`, you are putting an argument in the function name. What if there were 50 flavors?

Answer (score 1):

You've got all the technically correct answers, but the real issue here is the interface design, so I'd like to address that.

First, passing object's own private data as a parameter it its own method is ... well, bizarre, to say the least. Seems that you are trying to solve a low-level issue by exposing your internal implementation details to the user, and making him dependent on any internal changes.

My first question would be "is the `useVectorOfX` method ***really*** designed to work on **any** `vector<X>`?

- **yes**: you probably should have 2 methods, `doSomething(const vector<X>& clientsData)` and `doSomething() // using your private data`
- **no**: second question: "is this (***semantically***, from user's perspective, not code-wise) the same operation"?

  - **yes**: use one method with modifier, as per @nightcracker, e.g. `doSomething(A::highPrecision)`
  - **no**: use 2 methods as per @Bo. This will allow you to change the internal implementation in the future in a user-transparent way